# Adding LazyLoad - 'mat-icon' is not a known element

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have existing app, and now I want to add lazy loading.

My app structure is like this

```
app
 core
 |  |-shared.module.ts
 |  |-core.module.ts
 |
 |--home
 |     |
 |     |-home.component.ts
 |     |-home.component.html
 |     |-home.component.css
 |
 |--users
 |     |
 |     |-users.component.ts
 |     |-users.component.html
 |     |-users.component.css 
 |
 app.component.ts
 app.component.html
 app.component.css
 app.module.ts
 app-routing.module.ts
```

Now, In every component I add `home.module.ts and home-routing.module.ts` and `users.module.ts and home-routing.module.ts`

Also from my `app.module` I move all imports to `shared.module` and to `core.module`

Now, In my `app.module` looks like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from "@angular/core";
import { CoreModule } from "../../../core/core-module";
import { SharedModule } from "../../../core/shared.app.module.dependency";

 // views
 import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
 import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";

 import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
 import { HomeModule } from "./home/home.module";
 import { UsersModule } from "./users/users.module";

 @NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
        CoreModule,
        HomeModule,
        UsersModule
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AdminModule {}
```

In `core.module` I set this

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders, APP_INITIALIZER } from 
"@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from 
"@angular/common/http";
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform- 
browser/animations";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";

@NgModule({
imports: [CommonModule, BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, 
HttpClientModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, KeycloakAngularModule],
declarations: [],
exports: [BrowserModule]
})
export class CoreModule {}
```

In `shared.module` I import all that I need to my app, like angular-material (I set it to imports and on exports) also CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule etc...

And now, In my 'home.module' I import a shared module and component

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home.component";
import { SharedModule } from "projects/core/shared.app.module.dependency";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { HomeRoutingModule } from "./home-routing.module";

@NgModule({
   declarations: [HomeComponent],
   imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule, HomeRoutingModule, SharedModule]
   })
 export class HomeModule {}
```

But all the time I get errors in the console [image]

In a shared module, I import all material dependency. Before this, everything is worked properly

```
 A11yModule,
 CdkStepperModule,
 CdkTableModule,
 CdkTreeModule,
 DragDropModule,
 MatAutocompleteModule,
 MatBadgeModule,
 MatBottomSheetModule,
 MatButtonModule,
 MatButtonToggleModule,
 MatCardModule,
 MatCheckboxModule,
 MatChipsModule,
 MatStepperModule,
 MatDatepickerModule,
 MatDialogModule,
 MatDividerModule,
 MatExpansionModule,
 MatGridListModule,
 MatIconModule,
 MatInputModule,
 MatListModule,
 MatMenuModule,
 MatNativeDateModule,
 MatPaginatorModule,
 MatProgressBarModule,
 MatProgressSpinnerModule,
 MatRadioModule,
 MatRippleModule,
 MatSelectModule,
 MatSidenavModule,
 MatSliderModule,
 MatSlideToggleModule,
 MatSnackBarModule,
 MatSortModule,
 MatTableModule,
 MatTabsModule,
 MatToolbarModule,
 MatTooltipModule,
 MatTreeModule,
 PortalModule,
 ScrollingModule
```

Comment: did you import your `shared module` in your `app module`?

Comment: did you `exports:[MatIconModule]` in shared module?

Comment: @YashRami yes I import everything, you can see in my post I added my `app.module` in question

Comment: @KrishnaRathore yes, I export all mat module

Comment: What about the MatIconComponent? It is exported well or probably its selector is wrong!

Comment: @KiranShakya I only have `MatIconModule` not `MatIconComponent`

Comment: What I mean is, although you imported MatIconModule, it may not export MatIconComponent, which you are using in your template by its selector mat-icon

Comment: Can you explain me this little more detailed? Mabey this will be answer... Thank you